# Understanding SSR with AngularIO

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am trying to understand the basics of SSR and AngularIO (latest version). I understand that there is `CSR` and `SSR`, and their names should be self explanatory.

CSR does all the logic in the client - e.g. `<app-route>` is empty as expected.

However, SSR's behavior is not as expected.

I "turned on" SSR for my project and I see `<app-route>` is now filled with the corresponding HTML content. But I can also see that the HTTP request I make within the constructor of my component is still executed as well in the client. Why is that necessary if the server did that already (did it)?

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.files = new Array;
    this.http.get<any[]>("https://www.example.com/bar.json")
    .subscribe(data => this.files = Object.keys(data));
}
```

In the network section of the browser debugger I can see that `bar.json` is still loaded. Why is that?

Comment: Hello, are you using @nguniversal/*-engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From angulario SSR
If, for some reason, you are not using an @nguniversal/*-engine package, you may need to handle it yourself.

The recommended solution is to pass the full request URL to the options argument of renderModule() or renderModuleFactory() (depending on what you use to render AppServerModule on the server). This option is the least intrusive as it does not require any changes to the app. Here, "request URL" refers to the URL of the request as a response to which the app is being rendered on the server. For example, if the client requested https://my-server.com/dashboard and you are rendering the app on the server to respond to that request, options.url should be set to https://my-server.com/dashboard.

[Angular SSR](https://angular.io/guide/universal#using-absolute-urls-for-http-data-requests-on-the-server)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: Happy to have served ;)